# ValueError: Length of passed values is 100, index implies 10000

Tags: python, numpy, reshape

I am trying to reshape an array Z which has shape `(10000,)` to `(100,100)` as follows:

`Z = np.reshape(Z, (100, 100))`

I am getting the error:

`ValueError: Length of passed values is 100, index implies 10000.`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Double check `Z.shape`.  Also check `dtype`

Comment: Thanks. Z was a pandas series. Converted it to a numpy array and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try convert into Numpy array :

```
z.to_numpy()
```